# MySQL like statement error

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I'm trying to select a data with an applicant_id equal to 'Staff01' and I'm using this condition:

```
WHERE
IF (c.use_id_as_emp_no = '0', ccal.applicant_id, cc.contractor_idPK) LIKE '%staff01%'
```

What happens is that when I execute the query, there are no results. But if I remove the first letter of the string in the LIKE statement(which is s), there are results shown.

Another thing is that when I removed the IF statement on the condition above, which will look like this:

```
WHERE
ccal.applicant_id LIKE '%staff01%'
```

The data with the applicant_id Staff01 is shown.

Is it the IF statement that causes the LIKE function to malfunction? Please help me. I'm having a hard time on this. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: solved using LCASE() in comparisons

```
WHERE
IF (c.use_id_as_emp_no = '0', LCASE(ccal.applicant_id), cc.contractor_idPK) LIKE LCASE('%staff01%')
```

Comment: Try checking for case-sensitivity.

Comment: Have you tried without the IF statement ? Just with two WHERE clauses separated by a OR ?

Comment: @tsabz I tried and it works. but I need the If statement because if use_id_as_emp_no is not 0 then contractor_idPK must be checked instead of applicant_id

Comment: Given your latest comments, I suspect you want to match `Staff` against `staff` in a binary collation. If so, you've omitted relevant data.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario but when I removed the IF statement, the LIKE statement isn't case-sensitive. Why is it like that? When I replaced staff01 by Staff01, results are shown(on the condition with the IF statement).

Comment: thanks to all your help. I have done a solution to this problem, I added the LCASE() function to the selected field and in the LIKE statement:

(c.use_id_as_emp_no = '0', LCASE(ccal.applicant_id), cc.contractor_idPK) LIKE LCASE('%staff01%')

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
where IF (c.use_id_as_emp_no = '0', ccal.applicant_id, cc.contractor_idPK) 
COLLATE latin1_general_ci LIKE '%staff01%'
```

Comment: Then try `COLLATE latin1_bin` instead of `latin1_general_ci`

Comment: It's not working also. COLLATION 'latin1_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'

Comment: I tried placing the COLLATE latin1_bin after the LIKE statement and it says it's not valid for character set utf8.